# aws dynamodb ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I check ProvisionedThroughputExceededException in new aws sdk for dynamodb?I want to implement retry logic ,but the format of response is different from the older one.It no longer returns $response->isOK() and I am not able to get $response->body->to_array()->getArrayCopy() from the new response.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We are just catching the exception \Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, It is not thrown immediately when you hit the limit, it looks like the driver is waiting for response for some time and then throws it. So request will go slow at first.

Comment: Are you really catching the exception ? I am aware that this is a pretty old answer, so maybe something changed in the meantime... I just get an error level log, but no exception to catch.. I'd love to but I don't get it. Do you remember if you had to do something special to get it propagated ?

Comment: @LucaStucchi It was long a go so the driver code could have changed, I have moved job since so do not have access to that code anymore.

Comment: I imagined, 2015 is way too far ! Thanks anyway @TomaszSwider